# PyCharm reports wrong Python version

Tags: python, pycharm, versions

As per the screenshot, my system reports Python 3.6.5 but PyCharm is reporting the same file as 3.5.2.

Does anyone know how to fix?

[image]

EDIT: I suspect it is because for a previous project I set the interpreter version and set "Apply this to all future projects" option. And then upgraded Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the project is a free text string, you can change it to whatever you want. The real details are in the "interpreter path" when you go and edit an interpreter definition.

[image]

Click the cog wheel and select "Show All..."

[image]

Now you can see the real path.

I suspect the name just wasn't updated when you updated anaconda, but the Python version is actually the same as what you see in the command line. You can confirm this by running this from within pycharm:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If you see the old version, you can just add a new interpreter to PyCharm with the correct path to your Python 3.6 environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have both installed. I was using python 3.5.2, but recently updated to 3.6.2. I'd changed the `PATH` but pycharm was still displaying the old 3.5.2 version.

All you need to do is add the location of python 3.6.5 to your project interpreter list.

[image: Click the gear icon and select "Add Local"]

Click the gear icon in the top right, the select "Add Local". Then just add the location of python.exe for python 3.6.5.